# R. Forecast time series with R. Cannot plot autolayer

Tags: r, forecast

I am doing a forecast analysis and I would like to plot the training and testing set on a plot.
Here is my code:

```
library(forecast)
train <- head(AirPassengers, round(length(AirPassengers) * 0.6))
h <- length(AirPassengers) - length(train)
test <- tail(AirPassengers, h)

autoplot(train) + autolayer(test)
**Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only**
```

What Am I doing wrong?
When I use str() to check both train and test it says they are both Time-Series...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I ran your code and it worked fine to me. Try to do this: 1. Check `ggplot2` is installed. 2. Clean your environment and restart R

Comment: Thank you @Edo. ggplot2 is installed and updated.  I closed R, open it again, and ran the code and it was working. So I guess that one of the other packages that I am using is causing this. Thank you once again

Comment: Next time try to restart R with the following combination of keys: `Ctrl + Shift + F10` (Windows). You dont need to close it and reopen it back

Comment: That is a game changer! Many thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Edo's suggestion I realised that the problem is due to some package conflict.